# Manipulate YOLOv8 Results

Tags: object-detection, yolov8

How do you manipulate an empty results? (i.e. no detections)

For example:
`608x800 (no detections), 320.5ms`

Code:

```
    for box in boxes:
        if box.cls == 0:
            print("large bottled water")
        elif box.cls == 1:
            print("medium bottled water")
        elif box.cls == 2:
            print("medium soda")
        elif box.cls == 3:
            print("medium thick bottle")
        elif box.cls == 4:
            print("small bottled water")
        elif box.cls == 5:
            print("small soda")
        elif box.cls == 6:
            print("small thick bottle")
        elif box.cls == 7:
            print("small thick bottle")
        elif box.cls == 8:
            print("xs soda")
        elif box.cls == 9:
            print("xs thick bottle")
```

I only tried this one:

```
if box.cls == "":
   print("no detection")
```

I read the [documentation](https://docs.ultralytics.com/reference/engine/results/#ultralytics.engine.results.Boxes) and couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would check if a `result` is empty (no detection) before iterating. To get a plain `cls` value from a torch.Tensor: `cls = int(box.cls.item())`

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8s.pt')
results = model(source='image.jpg') # or different type of source

for result in results:
  if result:
    for box in result.boxes:
      cls = int(box.cls.item())
      if cls == 0:
          print("large bottled water")
      elif cls == 1:
          print("medium bottled water")
      elif cls == 2:
          print("medium soda")
  else:
    print("no detection")
```